# VBA: Check for odd/even numbers in a column and then check for correct value in another column

Tags: vba, excel

[Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9zM0.jpg)    [Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSBdR.jpg)I could need your help with this one:

I have birth numbers (11 or 10 digits) in column D(9). And I have a column N(9) with sex (M and F). I want to check if the text in column N is correct based on the birthnumber. If the 3rd last digit in the birthnumber contain an even number then it's female. If the 3rd digit is an odd number it's a male.
I want to use conditional formatting (mark the cell red) if M or F is wrong in column N.

Does anyone have a vba code for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I found this formula: "=MOD(INT(MOD(RC[-1],1000)/100),2)". 0=F og 1=M., but I struggle to put it togheter With conditional formatting and so on.

Comment: @TinMan. How can I change Your formula OR(AND(LEN(B9)=11,N9="M"),AND(LEN(B9)=9,N9="F")) to be based on the 3.rd last digit? I'm so sorry I didn't see that problem before.

Comment: I misread the question.  You should probably use James Cooke's answer to work out your solution.

Comment: Your formula worked beautifully when I have 11 digits in the birth number. But in some cases I can see that there is only 10 digits when the birth number starts at 0 (0 is skipped). So how can I modify Your formula to take this in to consideration? I think I have to look at the 3rd last digit (or digit 9 when there's 11 digits in total). James Cook's answer will give me the same problem.

Comment: `LEN(TEXT(B9,"00000000000"))` will return a 11 digit string that with lead zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatConditionally()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim birthNumbers As String
    Dim gender As String
    Dim genderCell As Range

    For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
        birthNumbers = Range("Table1[Birth number]")(i).Value
        Set genderCell = Range("Table1[F/M]")(i)
        gender = genderCell.Value

        If GenderIsValid(birthNumbers, gender) Then
            Call FormatAsValid(genderCell)
        Else
            Call FormatAsNotValid(genderCell)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub

Private Function GenderIsValid(birthNumbers As String, gender As String) As Boolean

    Dim lengthOfBirthNo As Integer
    Dim posOfGenderIdentifier As Integer
    Dim genderIdenfier As Integer
    Dim validGender As String

    lengthOfBirthNo = Len(birthNumbers)
    posOfGenderIdentifier = lengthOfBirthNo - 3

    genderIdenfier = Mid(birthNumbers, posOfGenderIdentifier, 1)

    If WorksheetFunction.IsEven(genderIdenfier) Then
        validGender = "F"
    Else
        validGender = "M"
    End If

    If (validGender = gender) Then
        GenderIsValid = True
    Else
        GenderIsValid = False
    End If

End Function

Private Sub FormatAsValid(rng As Range)
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    'sets fill color to RED
End Sub
Private Sub FormatAsNotValid(rng As Range)
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'sets fill color to WHITE
End Sub
```

Don't mind the size of the code. The public subroutine **(FormatConditionally)** is what needs to be run, and the column name should remain as-it-is, in the attached caption(or, be changed as appropriate).

And also it works with the *3rd-last* digit

I hope you would find it useful. Thank you.

Comment: @user9997971 You know... technically it's against stackoverflow's policy to post bare questions as-your-question-is right now. It should be accompanied with what you have personally done so far(most times --code sample). But you provided most of those in your comments, it would be helpful if you edit your question and add them.

Comment: Ok,I understand. This is the first time I use the web page. I have a lot to learn=)

Comment: @user9997971 Okay. I would like to know if you found my answer useful. If there is any challenge adpating it, I would be glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just do this with an excel formula for example and reference the ID; =IF(ISODD(MID(D3,9,1)),"M","F")

if the 9th value in cell D3 is odd then Male, else Female